# How to make variable accessible within jQuery .each() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, closures

This is and example of a frequent dilemma: how to make `markup` accessible inide this `.each()`?

I'm more interested in learning how to access outer variables from within a closure than I am in this specific issue.  I could fix this problem by assigning `markup` from inside the each function, but I'd rather learn a more elegant way to handle this kind of problem.

```
// hide form & display markup
function assessmentResults(){

  // get assessment responses
  var markup = parseForm();

  // show assessment results to user
  $('#cps-assess-form fieldset').each( function() {
    var q = $(this).find('.fieldset-wrapper');
    var i = 0;

    // hide form questions
    q.slideUp();

    // insert markup
    $('<div>'+markup[i]+'</div>').insertAfter(q);
    i++;
  });

}
```

Comment: markup _is_ already accessible inside your anonymous function assigned in the .each, this is exactly what closures are.

Comment: At the start of each iteration of `.each()` you are resetting the variable `i` to 0.

Comment: I think the `.each()` is overused, its also quite slow compared to traditional iterators. Why are people so scared to use the good old `for` loop?

Comment: @sweetamylase The nice thing about it is `this` is what you are after.

Comment: @epascarello The `this` just referring to one of the elements in the collection, which could easily be `var this = elements[i]`. By wrapping   the jQuery object around this `$(this)`, this step alone takes a bigger performance hit than `this = elements[i]`

Comment: @sweetamylase I know that, it is a convenience method. Everything that is a convenience has a cost. Just like how I spend a few extra bucks to have a pizza dropped off at my house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/each/), it already has an index!

```
.each( function(index, Element) )
```

No need for `i`

```
$('#cps-assess-form fieldset').each( function(index) {
    var q = $(this).find('.fieldset-wrapper').slideUp();
    $('<div/>').html(markup[index]).insertAfter(q);
});
```

The reason why yours is failing is the `i` is inside of the function so it is reset every iteration. You would need to move it outside of the function for it to work.